# PrimeNG datascroller conditional loader

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to implement [PrimeNG Data Scroller](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datascroller/loader) in one of my module. I want to show the 'Show More' button to load data only if there is more data to display, i.e. say if my array is having count more than 5 or so.

I have tried creating variable and using ngIf but then button action stops working. Here is my code snippet -

```html
<p-dataScroller [value]="filteredComments" [rows]="5" [loader]="loadButton">
                <p-header>
                    ..removed code for better clarity
                </p-header>
                <ng-template let-comment pTemplate="item">
                    .. removed code for better clarity
                </ng-template>
                <p-footer *ngIf="filteredComments.length > 5">
                    <span class="button btn-header btn-orange loaderButton" #loadButton>
                        Show More
                    </span>
                </p-footer>

            </p-dataScroller>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this issue by using the "visible" css style.  It isn't ideal, I'm not sure why that isn't taken care of by the component itself, but here's a way to tackle this yourself without extending their components:

```
<p-footer [style.visibility]="isMoreToLoad ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
  <span class="button btn-header btn-orange loaderButton">
  </span>
</p-footer>
```

And you can then setup the isMoreToLoad condition in your component to be any getter function etc.  Something like this would be an example:

```
get isMoreToLoad() : boolean {
  return this.filteredComments.length < this.totalFilteredComments;
}
```